# Ignoring line when exporting with latex backend

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have an org file that I want to export to both latex and html.

The file contains a bibliography, so I want to make sure that my org-exporter processes it correctly for both export backends.

For Latex things are easy, all I have to do is add the following:

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\printbibliography
#+END_EXPORT
```

For html, things are also simple. All I have to do is add the following:

```
bibliography:~/org/library.bib
```

The problem is that, when I export to latex, I get `\bibliography{../../org/library}` written at the end of the file, which is unnecessary.

What I want, thus, is to wrap the call to bibliography within an `IGNORE_LATEX` block. How can I achieve that?

```
# # What I would like to have:

#+IGNORE_LATEX
bibliography:~/org/library.bib
#+END_IGNORE
```

Comment: Can you put the bibliography link in an HTML block?

Comment: Thank you  =)  I tried `#+BEGIN_EXPORT html` first, but that was wrong. Using `#+BEGIN_HTML` is the correct solution. In any case, is there a simple way of ignoring a particular backend?

Comment: actually, `#+BEGIN_HTML` still inserts garbage into the latex output...

Answer (score 4):

I see what you want I think. If I use this org file:

```
A citation cite:akhade-2011-effec.


bibliographystyle:unsrt
bibliography:~/Dropbox/bibliography/references.bib
```

then it exports with bibliography to both html and latex. I use bibtex for the bibliography for latex, and org generates a minimal bibliography for html.  In general there is not a good way to get high quality bibliographies in html. The only option is unsorted, and there is no easy way to change it. The bibliography style is not used for the html export. You could check out http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/12/11/Introduction-to-a-citation-processor-in-org-ref/, which lays out what is needed to do that. It is basically a citation processor (which is what bibtex is for latex).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: bib/file/name apalike`

at the document location where you want to have the bibliography? (Org-mode 9.0.5, Emacs-25.1)

Comment: I tried that at first, before choosing to use biblatex. The actual syntax that worked for me was `bibliography:~/org/library.bib` followed by `bibliographystyle:apalike`. Problem is that the citations aren't sorted, and I couldn't find a way to fix it. After a while my patience ran out.

Comment: @dangom: Were the other styles (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles) not working for you?

Comment: Not all of them work, interestingly. `alpha` works, but `apalike` doesn't. Do I need to install something or use an extra package?

Comment: Is there any documentation for the `BIBLIOGRAPHY` keyword? I am searching `M-x info` for it but cannot find anything.